# Read the "value" being redeemed in a Bitcoin P2SH Script

Tags: script, p2sh, input

Is there any way for a Bitcoin P2SH Script to read the amount of Satoshis being redeemed?

Answer (score 1):

Inputs do not reference the value of the UTXO they spend. You need to look up the spent UTXO to find the value. Usually, this information is available to a node via the UTXO set, or can be looked up by inspecting the transaction that created the UTXO.